# String to character

Tags: c++

So I was asked to write a C++ program to implement a string object. Include member functions to compare two strings, concatenate two strings and find out whether the strings are palindrome or not.

This is my Code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class STR
{
    public:
        void concatenateFunction(string s1, string s2);
        void compareFunction(string s1, string s2) ;
        void palindromeFunction(char str[]);
};

void STR::compareFunction(string s1, string s2)
{
    // comparing both using inbuilt function
    int x = s1.compare(s2);
    cout<< "Compare:\n";
    if (x != 0)
        cout << s1 << " is not equal to "
             << s2 << endl;
    if (x > 0)
        cout << s1 << " is greater than "
             << s2 << endl;
    else
        cout << s2 << " is greater than "
             << s1 << "\n" << endl;
}

void STR::concatenateFunction(string s1, string s2, char c)
{
    string conc = s1 + s2;
    cout << "Concatenate:\n" << conc << "\n";

    std::string str = conc;

    char* c = strcpy(new char[str.length() + 1], str.c_str());
    return;
}

void STR:: palindromeFunction(char str[])
{
    int l = 0;
    int h = strlen(str) - 1;

    while (h > l)
    {
        if (str[l++] != str[h--])
        {
            cout << str << " is Not Palindrome";
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << str << " is Palindrome";
}

int main()
{
    STR res;
    char c;
    string s1,s2,conc;
    cout << "Enter a string 1: ";
    getline(cin, s1);

    cout << "Enter a string 2: ";
    getline(cin, s2);

    res.compareFunction(s1, s2);
    res.concatenateFunction(s1, s2);
    return 0;
}
```

If you see in the concatenateFunction i'm trying to get the concatenate as a character so that i can perform the palindrome function. but as it is a std its showing error. So is their any workaround to make my code run. Please do help.

Comment: Please indicate the exact line with the error, and the error message. Also, why are you using `new` and `strcpy`? The `std::string` container has better facilities.

Comment: Your functions return void and just print. This is probably not what is intended.

Comment: Neither the question nor the code have anything to do with OOP.

Comment: Your class has no members, the functions could be `static`

Comment: strcpy was me attempting different methods to convert it into character @cigien

Comment: Your class does not represent a string object, it's just a collection of functions, it has no data. Forget your actual question, you need to understand the task you've been given, because what you have at present will be a fail.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well it came from this subject.

Comment: @john in the pandemic we were given only notes so i'm following it as much as possible. And the only thing i'm stuck is the palindrome one.

Comment: Your `STR` class should contain data representing a string. That's what `implement a string object` means.

Comment: @AaronStoneA13 Well I can't see your notes, but none of the function you've written so far are correct because they do not implement a string object. They are string functions, but that is not the same thing. And no doubt you could write a palindrome string function, but that is not what you've been asked to do. You been asked to implement a string object.

Comment: Do you have in the notes something about data members? Constructors? Destructors?

Comment: `std::string` is the kind of string-representing class you should implement. Your member functions should not print anything but return things. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). (The point of exercises is almost never to produce a specific output, but to practice a specific method or technique. And becoming familiar with terminology.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the string class that you were requested to implement.

Functions are `void` and just print.

The class has no members. So it is not so OOP but rather a different way to write procedural code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Atleast a clear answer. So do you have any sites you can recommend

Comment: Do you not have a text book? There are some recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @AaronStoneA13 take a look at this one, read not only the question but also the answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98329/stdstring-implementation and try to figure out the basic things from your notes about classes. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be a type that represents a string - like a very basic version of `std::string`.

It should look something like this

```
class STR
{
    public:
        STR(const char* s);
        STR(const STR&);
        ~STR();
        STR& operator=(const STR& s);
        // Return the concatenation of this and 's'.
        STR concatenate(const STR& s) const;
        // Return -1, 0, or 1 if this is smaller, equal, or greater than 's' (like `strcmp`).
        int compare(const STR& s) const;
        // Retrun wheter this string is a palindrome.
        bool is_palindrome() const;
    private:
      // Suitable member variables.
};
```

And you would use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    STR s1("hello");
    STR s2("goodbye");
    STR s3 = s1.concatenate(s2);
    if (s3.compare("hellogoodbye") == 0)
        std::cout << "good\n";
    else
        std::cout << "not good\n";
   std::cout << "Is s1 a palindrome? " << s1.is_palindrome();
}
```